# Using Symfony2 controller return in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Symfony2 How do i get controller variables or returns in Twig file...? i.e. I have a function that return an array of results and I want to display these in twig file....?

Php Controller:

```
<?php

namespace TalkTalk\NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap\Factory;

use TalkTalk\NewsInfrastructure\Article\Factory\DbArticleReadRepository;
use TalkTalk\NewsInfrastructure\DatabaseRepository;

Class SitemapFactory extends DatabaseRepository{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $baseUrl = 'news/';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $feedsSlug;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $articleSlug;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $siteMap;

    /**
     * @array URLforSitemap[]
     */
    private $urls = array();

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getURLs()
    {
         $this->urls = $this->db->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('faf.article_id', 'faf.feed_id')
        ->addSelect('f.slug AS feedSlug')
        ->addSelect('a.slug AS articleSlug')
        ->addSelect("CONCAT('news/' , f.slug, '/' , a.slug) AS url")
        ->from('article_feeds', 'faf')
        ->leftJoin('faf', 'articles', 'a', 'faf.article_id = a.id')
        ->leftJoin('faf', 'feeds', 'f', 'faf.feed_id = f.id');

         return $this->urls->execute()->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function setSiteMap()
    {

        $this->siteMap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $this->siteMap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

        foreach($this->urls as $url){

            $this->siteMap .= '<url>';
            $this->siteMap .= '<loc>'.$url.'</loc>';
            $this->siteMap .= '<lastmod>2014-11-26</lastmod>';
            $this->siteMap .= '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>';
            $this->siteMap .= '<priority>0.5</priority>';
            $this->siteMap .= '<url>';

        }

        echo $this->siteMap .= '</urlset>';

    }

    public function getSiteMap()
    {
        return $this->siteMap;
    }
}
```

Twig File (SoFar):

```
{# src/TalkTalk/NewsInfrastructure/Sitemap/Views/sitemap.twig #}
<! DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}Sitemao{% endblock %} </title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>

    <h1>{{ Sitemap }}</h1>

    <ul>
        {% foreach test as url %}
            <li>{{  }}</li>


    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I now I can use for loops in twig between function brackiets {% %} and display a result between these brackiets {{ }} but I how do I bring the results of my controller into the twig file...?

Comment: first file is actualy not a Controler...

Comment: well it is a Factory class...with methods set/get so how do i pass these returns into a twig template

Comment: Maybe post your controller rather than the factory - people can then show you which part of your code to edit.

Comment: this is a Factory/Controller there is no distinct controller for this Factory.....?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off reading the manual for Symfony2. [This part covers the views](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html) and how to use them, which should help you get started.

Comment: So if I do this ``    public function setTwig()
    {
        $this->render('../View/sitemap.twig', array($this->urls));
    }